# Como se hace para mandar datos con UART de raspberry pi pico con bluethooth HC-05 hacia el movil?

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth

he visto muchos vídeos que usan el mismo comando para mandar una acción desde el celular al raspberry (encendido y apagado de led) ... Pero no sé y no encuentro que sea que presionando un pulsador mande un mensaje o notificación al celular que se pulsó algo, soy nuevo en microphyton y a su vez tengo que generar un APP MIT , me ayudarían mucho explicandome si realmente es posible o solo perdí mucho tiempo investigando :(  .. Dejo imagen del código (encendido y apagado de un led).[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSUKH.png)

Intenté usar este código sencillo como prueba(mencionando anteriormente , no sé el comando para enviar un dato que indique que se presionó tal botón) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEpLS.png)  y este APPMIT lo tomé de un proyecto de arduino que la verdad no sé si podría funcionarme con la raspberry [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldDQm.png)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, debes editar tu pregunta y agregar el código como texto y no como imagen. De todas formas, probaste usar la función uart.write? uart.write("El botón fue presionado")

Comment: Ya lo resolví.. Todo se debió por los baudrate de como lo dejaron configurado .... Aun así muchas gracias por recomendar lo de "uart.write" igual con ella pude confirmar que con ese comando es el que me sirve para enviar el mensaje hacia el celular.<3

Comment: Genial ;) recuerda marcar la pregunta como resuelta. Buen día!